# CGI.pm html output methods vs. simple print statements

Tags: html, perl, printing, cgi, output

There are several methods, a cgi script can output html. One of them is printing the html code as strings or as here document and another is creating a cgi object and using the cgi.pm methods.

My question is now, is there any difference between them and is there a way to combine both of them? For example i need to implement recaptcha with cgi.pm methods and want to add the cgi.pm code block between my print statements? Is this possible or did i miss something?

For me it seems like, that cgi.pm only supports the creation of basic html elements but not the creation of those who are often used for complex web design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually make CGI,pm print out any tag that you want (even ones that it doesn't support or ones that you have made up) by giving the name of the tag in the `use` statement.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

# Import standard functions, and add a madeuptag() function.
use CGI qw[:standard madeuptag];

say madeuptag("here it is"); # <madeuptag>here it is</madeuptag>
```

However, using the HTML generation functions is a **really bad idea**. And putting raw HTML in strings in your code is an **even worse idea**. You will be far better advised to use a templating system of some kind - I would recommend the [Template Toolkit](http://tt2.org/).

Oh, and for implementing reCAPTCHA, I recommend [Captcha::reCAPTCHA](https://metacpan.org/module/Captcha%3a%3areCAPTCHA).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to use a template toolkit. There was just no documentation on the internet which of the methods is better than the others. Now i got it! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

CGI.pm can be helpful when you want to print out certain key tags line by line, content by content, etc. with newline \n characters etc.

You can use something like HTML::Template: [http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTemplate)

This can be good for an entire html file with numerous variables you would like to replace.

There are several options, but for something like recaptcha and replacing a few variables, I would suggest a simple qq print statement:

```
print qq~<p><span><a href="~; print $link; $count++; 
print qq|">Title</a>
  </span>
</p>\n|;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Printing HTML from strings in your code is never a good idea. What happens when your web site becomes popular enough that you employ a front-end developer - someone who doesn't know Perl?

Comment: I agree with you Dave, but I don't appreciate the negative rating when I over answered his question.